# Function and Arithmetic progressions.

Tags: functions, arithmetic-progressions

$f: \mathbb{N} -› \mathbb{N}$

$f(1)=2$ and $f(n+1)=f(n)+4$ 
For $n \ge 1$. Calculate $f(135)$

I don't know how to start to solve

Comment: Can you guess an explicit form for $f(n)$? Try calculating a few consecutive values and see if you spot a pattern.

Comment: In this case, you have an easy recurrence relation $a_1=2$ , $a_{n+1}=a_n+4$ giving $2,6,10,14,18,22,\cdots$. Compare it with $4,8,12,16,20,24,\cdots$ and you should be able to guess the pattern easily.

Comment: @Peter I pasted your comment on my question to see clearly what you wrote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(n+1)=f(n)+4$
$ \Rightarrow  f(n+1) -f(n ) = 4 $
this means $f(n) $ is arithmetic progression with common difference 4 and whose first term is 2. Thus $f(135 ) = 2 + (135-1)4 = 538$

Comment: Thanks man, I didn't see that I could isolate the number 4 in the equation.